# Obter o timezone de uma data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Possuo essa data:

`2016-02-22T14:55:00.000-03:00`

E gostaria de pegar o timezone:

`-03:00`

De forma automática, sem precisar realizar nenhuma regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se essa data estiver retornando como uma string, podes utilizar [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

```js
var str = "2016-02-22T14:55:00.000-03:00";
var timezone = str.substr(str.length - 6);
console.log(timezone);
```

Se a data for no formato timestamp, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
var offset = new Date("2016-02-22T14:55:00.000-03:00").getTimezoneOffset();

var o = Math.abs(offset);

var timezone = (offset < 0 ? "+" : "-") + ("00" + Math.floor(o / 60)).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + (o % 60)).slice(-2);

console.log(timezone);
```

O método [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) retorna a diferença, em minutos, do UTC até a data/horário local. Depois ele verificar o valor em minutos e converte em horas ( divindo o valor por 60 ) e formata o valor de forma legível como hora e o operador (+/-).

[Fonte SoEn¹](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30377368/1432957)

Comment: Boa, porém se for formato timestamp ?

Comment: Adicionado alternativa, @Jonathan